# Azure synapse analytics parallel insert into staging table

Tags: azure, performance, load, azure-synapse

I am using dedicated SQL pool synapse with 500 DWU.
ADF is running under a workload classifier assigned to largerc group and with above_normal importance :

I have a stored procedure inside an ADF foreach loop, activities on the foreach loop run in parallel (max of 20 batch count in parallel).

The stored procedure is an INSERT INTO statement from an OPENJSON query (the table containing the json is on a replicated synapse table) to a staging HEAP synapse table.

The problem is when I query the dynamic view to monitor queries run on synapse I see that just one INSERT statement runs at a time all the others are suspended.

Is this a lock problem ? is their something to change on the query to do multiple insert at the same time.

[image]

This is the stored procedure inside the loop :

```
CREATE PROC [staging].[usp_stg_load_SrcChroniquesPGA] @file_name 
[varchar](100) AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = (select json_file from [staging]. 
[xml_to_json] where [file_name] = @file_name) ;

INSERT INTO [staging].[SrcChroniquesPGA]
select 
            @file_name as [NomFichier]
            ,[DatePublication],[NomSource],[Pas],[Type],[DateChronique]
            ,CASE WHEN Pas = 'H' AND DATEPART(hh, DateChronique) BETWEEN 0 AND 5 THEN DATEADD(day, -1, CAST(DateChronique AS DATE)) 
                    ELSE CAST(DateChronique AS DATE) END 
             AS [DateJourneeGaziere]
            ,[HorodateMaj],[Qualite]
            ,[ValeurChronique],[DateStatut],[HorodateMajStatut],[ValeurStatut]
    from OPENJSON( @json ,'$') 
    WITH (
        [DatePublication] [datetime2](7) '$.Transaction.HorodateInfos',
        [PGA] nvarchar(MAX) '$.PGA' as JSON
    ) j
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(PGA)
    WITH (
        [NomSource] [nvarchar](256) '$.PCEIdentification.NomSource',
        [PGAStatut] nvarchar(MAX) '$.PGAStatut' as JSON,
        [PGAChronique] nvarchar(MAX) '$.PGAChronique' as JSON
    )
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(PGAChronique)
    WITH (
        [Pas] [nvarchar](256) '$.Pas',
        [Type] [nvarchar](256) '$.Type',
        --[Unite] nvarchar(100) '$.Unite',
        [Mesure]  nvarchar(MAX) '$.Mesure' as JSON
    ) 
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([Mesure])
    WITH (
        [DateChronique] [datetime2](7) '$.Date',
        [ValeurChronique] [float] '$.Valeur',
        [HorodateMaj] [datetime2](7) '$.HorodateMaj',
        [Qualite] [nvarchar](256) '$.Qualite'
    ) msr
    
    OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(PGAStatut)
            WITH (
                [DateStatut] [datetime2](7) '$.Date',
                [HorodateMajStatut] [datetime2](7) '$.HorodateMaj',
                [ValeurStatut] [nvarchar](256) '$.Valeur'
            )
            WHERE [DateStatut] = [DateChronique]
                
                ) jj

END
```

Comment: When considering dedicated SQL pool performance and parallelism, you also consider the DWU you are running at and the resource class it is allocated to.  Or are you using workload classification?  Please add the above information to your post.

Comment: @wBob I added requested informations above ;)

Comment: Can you share your INSERT statement? I’m thinking that the best approach is to get rid of the for loop and change it to a single insert statement which parses all JSON rows. That should drastically improve performance and eliminate locking on the (as I understand it) single destination table.

Comment: @GregGalloway I added the ISERT INTO stored srocedure;
I tried to concatenate all the json file directely an a sql variable but this lead to an error because it exceed  2GB.

Comment: Instead of `FROM OPENJSON` try `FROM staging.xml_to_json CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(json_file)`… does that make sense? And load all the file paths in one insert

Comment: @GregGalloway Yes!! it's working. That drastically improve performance
Thank you

Comment: @okr great! Glad to help. I posted as an answer for the benefit of the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to get rid of the for loop in ADF and change it to a single insert statement which parses all JSON rows. That should drastically improve performance and eliminate locking on the single destination table. I believe locking is the fundamental blocker. But also in Synapse large inserts perform better than thousands of small inserts.

I would recommend you refactor your `INSERT` statement. Instead of `FROM OPENJSON( @json ,'$')` try `FROM staging.xml_to_json CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(json_file)`… You should try to load all the file paths in one insert.

Answer (score 0):

So as per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/memory-concurrency-limits) DWU 500 has 20 concurrent queries, 20 concurrency slots and largerc takes 4 slots.  So the maximum concurrency you can expect is 5 and that does not include any other queries running.

I would suggest lowering the resource class or trying a static resource class.  You could also try raising the DWU but obviously this is more expensive.  Experiment with your workload to see what works best.  It is strange you are only getting one query running at a time - check your For Each activity is not running in sequential mode and use the DMVs (sys.dm_pdw_exec_requests) to check for other queries executing and queuing.